# How to set a cookie to a WebView?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have a Fragment with a `WebView` and I want set a cookie that I have get her string "name=value".

The following SO links recommend to do a sleep after doing "cookieManager.removeSessionCookie()".

[Android WebView Cookie Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

The code of my AsyncTask is that follows:

```
private class WebViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String sessionCookie;
    CookieManager cookieManager;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
        cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        sessionCookie = cookieManager.getCookie(BASE_URL);

        if (sessionCookie != null) {
            sessionCookie = sessionCookie + "; domain=" + BASE_URL;
            /* delete old cookies */
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        }

        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... param) {
        /* this is very important - THIS IS THE HACK */
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if (sessionCookie != null) {
            cookieManager.setCookie(BASE_URL, sessionCookie);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        }

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(EDIT_URL);
    }
}
```

In that code I get correctly the sessionCookie with the format: "name=value" and later I add ;domain=BASE_URL.

How I set the session cookie correctly to the WebView?

**PD:**

- mWebView is the `WebView` inside a fragment that I want to set the cookie.
- This `AsyncTask` is executed from the `onCreateView` method of a `Fragment` after getting the mWebView object.
- If it helps, I use *robospice* and *retrofit* libraries.

**Others SO questions checked:**

- [Android CookieManager setCookie doesn't set anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700310/android-cookiemanager-setcookie-doesnt-set-anything)
- [Cookies & Webview - CookieSyncManager in Android!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729266/cookies-webview-cookiesyncmanager-in-android)
- [How to remove cookies using CookieManager for a specific domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834180/how-to-remove-cookies-using-cookiemanager-for-a-specific-domain/11621738#11621738)
- [android cookies issue in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272597/android-cookies-issue-in-application)
- [Set a cookie to a webView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716898/set-a-cookie-to-a-webview-in-android)

Thanks in advance.